# MOCKITO: What is it and how is it different from Junit

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want to know what Mockito is.

Is it supporting JUnit or is it an environment for writing JUnit test cases?

Can someone please explain to me the differences between JUnit and Mockito?

Comment: Isn't your question explained at http://mockito.org/? If not than be more specific.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

JUnit is a framework that helps with writing and running your unit tests.

Mockito (or any other mocking tool) is a framework that you specifically use to efficiently write certain kind of tests. At its core, any mocking framework allows you to omit instantiating "real" objects of production classes, instead the mocking framework creates a stub for you. Doing so gives you full control over that mocked object and enables you to verify the interactions taking place, for example.

Having said that, one core aspect in unit testing is the fact that you want to isolate your "class under test" from anything else in the world. In order to do that, you very often have to create "test doubles" that you provide to an object of your "class under test". You could create all those "test doubles" manually; or you use a mocking framework that **generates** object of a certain class for you using reflection techniques. Interestingly enough, some people advocate to never use mocking frameworks, but honestly I can't imagine doing that.

In other words, you can definitely use JUnit without using a mocking framework. Same is true for the reverse direction, but in reality, there are not many good reasons why you would want to use Mockito for anything else but unit testing.

Comment: So if you include mockito libraries does it include Junit libraries by default?

Comment: First thing to understand: these are **different** products. Besides the fact that you typically use them together, all of those "things" are independent of each other. Thus do do not include each other. But really: that is not something you should ask about: turn to the home pages for each of those products; and read their documentation. Don't rely on people explaining you stuff that is documented in plain sight.

Comment: I am one of those that advocate to avoid using mocking libraries (even though I develop one!). After many years of experience, I realized that it usually leads to bad tests. People have a strong tendency to overuse/abuse/misuse the mocking tool. Instead, I prefer integration tests. Interestingly, well-known "gurus" (including the "creator" of TDD) also don't like mocking; they write *non-isolated* unit tests - for reference, see [this article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html).

Comment: @Rogério I think I am somehow on middle ground here. I absolutely prefer unit tests (in the more narrow definition) that do not require mocking. Because the test is just much more elegant; and you know, specifying the behavior of a mock - that is about testing the internal implementation of your class under test. But: a lot of the core classes/objects in our product only work reasonably when our whole product runs. If I need to use something from there, I have two choices: use mocking; or go for some "functional test" that takes me 10 **minutes** to prepare and that is **hard** to execute ...

Comment: @Rogério and that is almost impossible to automate, because we don't have good means for automation of functional tests. So, you do the math; which of the two options gives me quicker feedback?!

Comment: Oh, I completely agree that *functional* tests are not practical. I tried them both in C#.NET (using the WatiN tool) and in Java (using WebDriver). In both cases, it was a pain, particularly to *run* the tests. Instead, I write *out-of-container* integration tests which are fast and stable enough to not discourage the developer from running them at any time.

Answer (score 19):

JUnit is the Java library used to write tests (offers support for running tests and different extra helpers - like setup and teardown methods, test sets etc.). 
Mockito is a library that enables writing tests using the [mocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) approach.

See here a nice article on the mocking vs non mocking tests: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Answer (score 13):

***Layman's Explanation with Example***

JUnit is used to test APIs in source code. To test APIs in JUnit, sometimes we may require data classes. To create those, we can use mockito.

Mock refers to creating duplicate or dummy objects.

We might be using many data classes in the project. For example, think of a Student object. It might have some 10 parameters like id, age, marks, gender etc. But you have one API to return a list of students whose age is greater than 10. So, to test this API we need to create student objects with all 10 parameters right. It is difficult. So, we can mock objects only with the required parameters. In our scenario, we will mock student objects with only age as a parameter.

```
Student student1=mock(Student.class);
when(student1.getAge()).thenReturn(20);

Student student2=mock(Student.class);
when(student2.getAge()).thenReturn(8);
```

So,above 2 objects can be added to a list and can be passed to API to test if API returns students who has age greater than 10.